# Unity Monodevelop and .Net framework

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am trying to use Unity and monodevelop on a windows 10 computer. Every time I run to debug/compile my script I get the following error.

Error MSB3645: .NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 was not found. In order to target ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5", .NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 or later must be installed. (MSB3645) (Assembly-CSharp)

I have tried installing .Net update but as I have just downloaded visual studio I have the most recent version.

Can anyone help. I would prefer to use monodevelop over VS as VS seems to really use a lot of resources on my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Framework 3.5 is a system component, so you need to enable it at Control Panel | Programs,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

[image]